# Creating an AVAssetDownloadURLSession requires the com.apple.developer.media-asset-download entitlement

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, entitlements, avasset

When I try to build the instance of AVAssetDownloadURLSession in iOS 9.0, it had a exception.

**Reason**: 'Creating an AVAssetDownloadURLSession requires the com.apple.developer.media-asset-download entitlement'.

I don't know how to solve the question. Please help me.

My code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"AX"];
configuration.HTTPCookieAcceptPolicy = NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyOnlyFromMainDocumentDomain;
configuration.shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode = YES;
configuration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = YES;
configuration.HTTPShouldSetCookies = YES;
configuration.HTTPShouldUsePipelining = NO;
configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy;
configuration.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60.0;
configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10;
configuration.discretionary = YES;

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3;

AVAssetDownloadURLSession *session = [AVAssetDownloadURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration assetDownloadDelegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
```

Comment: Hi did you solve the issue? I found this crash also happens in real device

Answer (score 2):

**AVDownloadURLSession works on devices only**. If your trying it on simulator it will crash. Try to run this code on device. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

@martin 's answer is correct. Use `TARGET_IOS_SIMULATOR` commenting out the `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`related code for debugging on a simulator.